# Validar inasistencias con php

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

Hola chic@s tengo una duda de como mostrar un dato que no existe en la base de datos...
explico tengo un arreglo en la cual guardo la asistencia de los alumnos la cual esta separada por id, fecha, entrada y salida
$fecha2 es una validación para filtrar por una fecha predeterminada...

```
$co= true;
        $co1= 0;
        $co2= 0;
        while ($co=true) {
            if ($c2[$co1][0]==null) {
                $co= false;
                break;
            }
            if ($co2 == 2) {
             $arreglo2[$co2][0] = $arreglo1[$co1][0];  //id
             $arreglo2[$co2][2] = $arreglo1[$co1][2];  //fecha
             $arreglo2[$co2][3] = $arreglo1[$co1][3];  //entrada
             $arreglo2[$co2][4] = $arreglo1[$co1][4];  //salida
            }
             else {
                   //aqui hace el filtrado por fecha y la cual funciona bien... el problema es que si un alumno tiene alguna falta osea no tiene un registro del día.. esto afecta el orden de la vista... ya que todo se recorre hacia arriba...
           if ($fecha2=== $c2[$con25][2]) {
             $co2++;
                 $arreglo2[$co2][0] = $arreglo1[$co1][0];  //id
                 $arreglo2[$co2][2] = $arreglo1[$co1][2];  //fecha
                 $arreglo2[$co2][3] = $arreglo1[$co1][3];  //inicio
                 $arreglo2[$co2][4] = $arreglo1[$co1][4];  //salida
                            }else {
//aquí trato de comparar las inasistencias ya que al tener un alumno alguna... los registros se recorren hacia arriba... bueno esto afecta la vista de una tabla que se obtiene en en html... 
                            if (($fecha2 === $arreglo1[$co1][2]) == null) {
                         $co2++;
                 $arreglo2[$co2][0] = 0;  //id
                 $arreglo2[$co2][2] = 0;  //fecha
                 $arreglo2[$co2][3] = 0;  //inicio
                 $arreglo2[$co2][4] = 0;  //salida
                                      }
                               }
                        }
        $co1++;
        }
```

//simulacion de la tabla de la  base de datos

Id_alumno    Asistencia
1       2018-11-01

2       2018-11-01

4       2018-11-01

5       2018-11-01

6       2018-11-01

7       2018-11-01

8       2018-11-01

10      2018-11-01

Id_alumno    Asistencia

2       2018-11-02

3       2018-11-02

4       2018-11-02

5       2018-11-02

9       2018-11-02

11      2018-11-02

12      2018-11-02

espero puedan ayudarme saludos....

Answer (score 0):

¿Tienes el período de duración de clases? primero debes saber cuales son todas las fechas del curso, si no lo tienes has un distinct a las fechas de los estudiantes de ese curso... (vaya parece que pueden haber muchos casos aqui)

luego solo compara, si la fecha existe asistió si no existe no asistió. 
Te muestro la lógica opuesta yo guardo las inasistencias

```
               foreach ($Ina->Est() as $columna => $row) {
                            $stmtFechas = $Ina->Inansistencia($row['ESTID']);
                            //Es activo el estudiante
                            if ($row['Estado'] == 1) {
                                echo"<tr id='" . $row['ESTID'] . "' ><td style='font-size: 70%;'>" . utf8_encode($row['NOMBRE']) . "</td>";
                                foreach ($stmtFechas as $columna2 => $row2) {
                                    if ($row2['falto'] == 1) {
                                        echo"<td value='" . $row2['fecha'] ."' class='text-center selected'><input type='checkbox' checked></td>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo"<td value='" . $row2['fecha'] . "' class='text-center'><input type='checkbox'></td>";
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo"<tr class='danger'><td style='font-size: 70%;'>" . utf8_encode($row['NOMBRE']) . "</td>";
                                foreach ($stmtFechas as $columna2 => $row2) {
                                    if ($row2['falto'] == 1) {
                                        echo"<td  value='" . $row2['fecha'] . "' class='text-center selected' ><input type='checkbox' checked disabled></td>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo"<td  value='" . $row2['fecha'] . "' class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' disabled></td>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
```

Un saludo